# Populate div with select from multi array JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm really new on json, and I'm trying to show some info from json data, via select. Its possible??

```
[
{
  "id": 1,
  "country": "Spain",
  "more": [
      {
        "city": "Barcelona",
        "age": 1992,
        "language": "catalan",
      },
      {
        "city": "Madrid",
        "age": 2001,
        "language": "spanish",
      }
  ]
},
{
"id": 2,
"country": "Portugual",
"more": [
    {
      "city": "Porto",
      "age": 2009,
      "language": "portuguese",
    },
    {
     "city": "Madeira",
     "age": 1997,
     "language": "portuguese",
    }
  ]
}
]
```

so, I have a select that works with this .js file:

```
var json = '[{"id":1,"country":"Spain","more"[{"city":"Barcelona","age":1992,"language":"catalan",},{"city":"Madrid","age":2001,"language":"spanish",}]},{"id":2,"country":"Portugual","more":[{"country":"Porto","age":2009,"language":"portuguese",},{"country":"Madeira","age":1997,"language":"portuguese",}]}]';

var items = JSON.parse(json);
var $selectElement = $("#list");

$(items).each(function(){
  var option = '<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.city + '</option>';
  $selectElement.append(option);
});
```

this is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Select the city:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list" name="list"> 
  </select>
</div>

<div id="info">
  <h1><span class="city">  </span></h2>
  <h2><span class="age"> </span></h2>
  <h3><span class="language">  </span></h3>
</div>
```

and now I would like to make when select the Country, populate an HTML "more" -from json- information, and change when I change the option in a select. 
I will be grateful if someone can help me!

EDIT -- All of answers works perfectly. I accepted the question that I chose to use! -- Thanks!

Comment: Your `var json` is invalid JSON (missing `:`) ...typo?

Comment: So what have you tried to do that?

Comment: *`populate an HTML "more"`*... can you be a bit more precise? Just by showing the expected HTML structure would help a lot.

Comment: @Hardy I'm looking for how i can do this, because I don't know!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "more" came from array, and put into an html.. I can catch id and country in my select, and I would like to show the other info when I select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is an Array with Object with Array with Object. Therefore you should loop through the arrays to get the values you need for selected option.
This [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8Lhvxw3/2/) should work.

```
 $('body').on('change', '#list', function() {
  var selectedOption = this.value;
  $(items).each(function() {
    if (this.id.toString() === selectedOption) {
      $('#info').html(returnData(this.more));
      return;
    }
  })
})

var returnData = function(arr) {
  var t = '';
  console.log(arr)
  $(arr).each(function() {
    var objKeys = Object.keys(this);
    console.log(objKeys)
    var s = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i++) {
      s += '<h' + (i + 1) + '><span class="' + objKeys[i] + '">' + this[objKeys[i]] + '</span></h' + (i + 1) + '>';
      console.log(s, objKeys[i])
    }
    t += s;
  });
  return t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to loop through and get the value from `more`:

```
$("#list").on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  $('#info').empty();
  $(items).each(function() {
    if (this.id == id) {
      $(this.more).each(function() {
        $('#info').append('<h1><span class="city">' + this.city + ' </span></h1>' +
          '<h2><span class="age"> ' + this.age + '</span></h2>' +
          '<h3> <span class="language">' + this.language + '  </span></h3>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tshseg0w/2/). And it is the simplest way to do so.

Comment: Thank for your time! works perfectly and is very simple to understand!!

Comment: It's possible to put each result in a different div?

Answer (score 0):

Either you need more than one `select` or you need to combine country info with city info (with two loops) if you want to use one `select`. Below is how you can use two `select` elements:

```js
var items = [{
  "id": 1,
  "country": "Spain",
  "more": [
      {
        "city": "Barcelona",
        "age": 1992,
        "language": "catalan",
      },
      {
        "city": "Madrid",
        "age": 2001,
        "language": "spanish",
      }
  ]
},
{
"id": 2,
"country": "Portugual",
"more": [
    {
      "city": "Porto",
      "age": 2009,
      "language": "portuguese",
    },
    {
     "city": "Madeira",
     "age": 1997,
     "language": "portuguese",
    }
  ]
}],
    opt  = $('<option/>'),
    sel  = $('#list'),
    city = $('#city'),
    info = $('#info');

$.each( items, function(i, item) {
    opt.clone().val( item.id ).text( item.country ).data('cities', item.more).appendTo( sel );
});

sel.on('change', function() {
    city.empty();
    var data = $('option:selected',this).data('cities');
    $.each( data, function(j, cty) {
        opt.clone().val( j ).text( cty.city ).data('city', cty).appendTo( city );
    });
    city.change();
})
.change();

city.on('change', function() {
    var cityData = $('option:selected',this).data('city');
    info.find('.city').html( cityData.city );
    info.find('.age').html( cityData.age );
    info.find('.language').html( cityData.language );
})
.change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select Country:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="list" name="list"> 
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select the city:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city"> 
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 info" id="info">
  <h1><span class="city">  </span></h2>
  <h2><span class="age"> </span></h2>
  <h3> <span class="language">  </span></h3>
</div>
```